# JPA CRITERIA QUERY with order by joined columns

Tags: jpa, criteria-api

How to invoke order by on a joined entity? I am trying to achieve the following with:

select * from person p inner join telephone t on p.id=t.person_id join sim s on s.id=t.sim_id order by s.name DESC

```
@Entity
public class Person implements Serializable{
    @Id
    private Long id;
    @OneToMany(orphanRemoval = true, mappedBy = "person", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    private List<Telephone> telephonesNumber;

@Entity
public class Telephone implements Serializable {
    @Id
    private String number;
    @Id
    @ManyToOne()
    @JoinColumn(name = "person_id")
    private Person person;
    @Id
    @ManyToOne(cascade = {})
    @JoinColumn(name = "sim_id")
    private Sim sim;

@Entity
public class Sim implements Serializable {
    @Id
    private Long id;
    @Column(unique = true)
    private String name;
```

I use specification interface, in this example sorting is on the field person.id and it works

```
public class PersonSpecification implements Specification<Person> {

    @Override
    public Predicate toPredicate(Root<Person> root, CriteriaQuery<?> query, CriteriaBuilder builder) {
         List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>();
// there is many different conditions for example
//       if(someCondition!=null) {
//          predicates.add(builder.like(root.get("someProperty"), someValue));
//      }


        query.groupBy(root.get("id"));
        //there I want to order by Sim.name i dont know how
        query.orderBy(builder.asc(root.get("phone")));//this works
        return  builder.and((predicates.toArray(new Predicate[predicates.size()])));
    }
```

I want to order by Sim.name but i dont know how.

Comment: where is your Criteria query that you have tried?

Comment: thx for question, i update my post about what I managed to do so far

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In JPA specification you can use:

```
query.orderBy(builder.asc(root.join("telephonesNumber").get("sim").get("name")));
```

to sort by sim name.

For more details:
https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Querying#Joining.2C_querying_on_a_OneToMany_relationship

If you using JPA Query:

```
@Query("select s from Person p 
        join p.telephonesNumber t 
        join t.sim s order 
        by t.sim.id desc")
```

It will produce this:

```
select * from person p 
inner join telephone t on p.id=t.person_id 
inner join sim s on t.sim_id=s.id 
order by t.sim_id desc
```

For more details:

https://github.com/abhilekhsingh041992/spring-boot-samples/blob/master/jpa/src/main/java/example/springboot/jpa/repository/PersonRepository.java

Comment: thx for reply, I need solution not for Repository but in my Specification class, i need sort my entity by sim.name, sorry for the mistake, I update my post

Comment: I didn't know that. Please check the edit and let me know if it works.

Answer (score 0):

another way for that would be using Query method:

```
  List<Telephone> findAllByOrderBySimIdAsc();
```

Look at this findAllByOrderBy**SimId**Asc

With the code before, you can get all rows from Telephone ordered by Sim Id.